# Problems in getting EER from FAR and FRR

Tags: roc

I have 80 classes and computed FAR, FRR. But having problem in computing EER, bcz FAR and FRR have zero values multiple times. So how to compute EER, bcz as per definition of EER, it is the point where FAR and FRR are same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! It's very hard to answer your question, I have no idea what you're asking or what you have done already. Have a look at this help page to learn how to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask